# Change dynamically the concurrency factor in mergeMap operator

Tags: rxjs

I have an Observable, `mySourceObs`, and the following code

```
concurrencyFactor = 10;
mySourceObs.pipe(
  mergeMap(data => generateAnotherObservable(data), concurrencyFactor)
).subscribe();
```

Is there a way to change dynamically the `concurrencyFactor` once the chain of Observables has been subscribed?

Comment: what is the purpose of doing so in real world problem?

Comment: The reason is to be able to dynamically "live" change the concurrency of the processing. Suppose you have to call many REST apis of a remote server in parallel, let's say 1.000. At the same time you know that you can not exceed a certain level of parallelism otherwise the remote server crashes. You may use `mergeMap` with its concurrency set to a certain value, let's say 10. During the execution of these remote invocations, you realize you can increase the level of parallelism. In this case I would like to be capable to increase concurrency level without having to relaunch the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, but inner observable will restart when concurrencyFactor changes.

```
concurrencyFactor = new BehaviorSubject(10);
combineLatest(mySourceObs,concurrent).pipe(
  switchMap(([data,concurrent]) => generateAnotherObservable(data), concurrent)
).subscribe();

concurrencyFactor.next(5)
```

Comment: I am afraid this solution does not pass the compilation phase (in TypeScript). The core reason is that the input parameter `concurrent` of the function `(data,concurrent) => generateAnotherObservable(data)` is visible only within the scope of the function, while `concurrent` parameter of `switchMap`, which I am not aware of, is outside that scope

Comment: i missed an array variable explode in my code. edited. hope it works

Comment: the problem I highlighted unfortunately remains

Comment: If u create a stackbliz maybe I can help. Typing shouldn’t be a show breaker

Comment: I can not create a stackblitz. I am not even able to make it pass the compiler. Are you able to make it compile from TypeScript? The point is that the `concurrent` input variable is not in the same scope as the `concurrent` parameter of `switchMap`. And, by the way, `switchMap` does not seem to have a concurrency parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way of controlling the `concurrency` of `mergeMap` with a combination of an external `Subject`, `switchMap` and `defer`.

This is the sample code

```
// when this Observable emits, the concurrency is recalculated
const mySwitch = new Subject<number>();
let myConcurrency = 1;

// this block emits five times, every time setting a new value for the concurrency
// and the making mySwitch emit
merge(interval(1000).pipe(map(i => i + 2)), of(1))
  .pipe(
    delay(0),
    take(5),
    tap(i => {
      myConcurrency = i * 2;
      console.log("switch emitted", i);
      mySwitch.next(i);
    })
  )
  .subscribe();

// source is an hot Observable which emits an incresing number every 100 ms
const source = new Subject<number>();
interval(100)
  .pipe(take(100))
  .subscribe(i => source.next(i));

// this is the core of the logic
// every time mySwitch emits the old subscription is cancelled and a new one is created
mySwitch
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      // defer is critical here since we want a new Observable to be generated at subscription time
      // so that the new concurrency value is actually used
      defer(() =>
        source.pipe(
          mergeMap(
            i =>
              // this is just a simulation of a an inner Observable emitting something
              interval(100).pipe(
                delay(100),
                map(j => `Observable of ${i} and ${j}`),
                take(10)
              ),
            myConcurrency
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: data => console.log(data)
  });
```